# Generating non repeating strings in c#

Tags: c#, .net, string, random, .net-core

Currently I am writing a console based program in .net Core 3.1. The goal of the program is to have the user input a string and then the console will attempt to guess it. Example:

```
What shall I guess: string
Ok Guessing String...

Code Cracked :) Your code is: string
```

Anyways while I was creating the program I ran into a problem. The randomly generated string I created was repeating quite frequently, and if the codes were longer the problem exponentially increased.

I used this for my random string generation

```
string passw = Console.Readline();

for (int i = 0; i > -1; i++)
            {
                var chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
                var stringChars = new char[passw.Length];

                for (int a = 0; a < passw.Length; a++)
                {
                    stringChars[a] = chars[rnd.Next(chars.Length)];
                }

                var finalstring = new String(stringChars);
                Console.WriteLine(finalstring);

                if (finalstring== passw)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    Console.WriteLine("Password Guessed: " + finalstring);
                    Console.WriteLine("It took a total of: " + i + " guesses!");
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }
            }
```

How can I accomplish the goal? I saw some things about lists and similar things but was wondering if there was a better way to get the result I am looking for. Thank you! I can clarify anything if needed!

Comment: shuffle your `chars` and take `passw.Length` of them.  Gobs and gobs of examples here

Comment: "The randomly generated string I created was repeating quite frequently"  Usually this is caused by creating your instance of `Random` INSIDE the loop.  Do you have that in your actual code but not showing here?

Comment: Could you explain the shuffle method more, and my instance or random is outside the loop. I was just noticing the fact that as It created more it became very noticeable of the amount of repeats

Comment: I'm not seeing any repeats...can you post your complete code please?

Comment: When you say “repeats” do you mean identical `finalstring`s get written to the console over and over? Or do you mean that each specific `finalstring` sometimes contains the same character more than once?

Comment: "I can clarify anything if needed!" but the lack of response to Idle_Mind suggests otherwise.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of responses. I mean that "each specific finalstring sometimes contains the same character more than once."

Comment: Well...that's possible since you are simply repeatedly picking a character from the string.  If you don't want to repeat any characters, then shuffle the order of the characters and take just the first X of them.

Comment: ...but what if the user types in a string that has a repeat?...then you'll never guess their password!

Comment: Ahh I see. I apologize again for my delayed responses. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a word guessing demo, done "hollywood" style:

[image]

Final output:

[image]

Because you should always show your progress when "cracking" a password...and "crack" it by guessing a random sorted order of letters?

Produced by:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string guess;
    char response;
    int tries = 0;            
    Random rnd = new Random();
    var chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".ToCharArray();

    do
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.Write("Enter a word with no characters repeated in it: ");
        string wordToGuess = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

        var letters = wordToGuess.ToCharArray().Distinct();
        if (letters.All(c => char.IsLetter(c)) && letters.Count() == wordToGuess.Length && wordToGuess.Length > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Trying to guess your word...");
            int row = Console.CursorTop;
            Console.CursorVisible = false;
            tries = 0;
            do
            {
                tries++;
                var shuffled = (chars.OrderBy(c => rnd.Next())).ToArray();
                guess = new String(shuffled.Take(wordToGuess.Length).ToArray());
                Console.SetCursorPosition(0, row);
                Console.WriteLine("chars = " + new string(shuffled));
                Console.Write("Guess: {0}, Tries: {1}", guess, tries.ToString("N0"));
            } while (guess != wordToGuess);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("It took me {0} tries to guess your word: {1}", tries.ToString("N0"), guess);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid word to guess!");
        }
       
        Console.CursorVisible = true;
        Console.Write("Play again? Y/N: ");
        response = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
        Console.WriteLine();
    } while (response == 'y' || response == 'Y');
                
    Console.Write("Press Enter to Quit");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: This is a very cool way of accomplishing the task I had. By removing ".distinct()" It would be able to guess words with repeated characters correct?

Comment: Well, removing `.Distinct()` (and related code) would allow the USER to enter a word that had repeating characters.  The random word algorithm, however, does NOT allow duplicates because the "char" string only has ONE of each letter and all we are doing is shuffling the order of those characters and taking the first X of them.